# Running a .sh to execute multiple commands

Tags: command-line, bash, .desktop

I was curious how I would go about running multiple commands via shell script.

For example, just to try it out, I'd like to be able to connect a .desktop to a .sh that will run all the update codes so I don't have to type it out. I know how to execute a single command via a .sh, not multiple.

Any way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple really - you need to separate the commands. For instance this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

will update the package lists, and then the packages. Another possibility is this *(probably better, as the && will only allow the `upgrade` command to run if the `update` exits successfully)*:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This should run the commands for updating the list of packages and then the package themselves. This would need to be saved into a text file (e.g. `updatescript` in the home directory). You can then make it executable by running:

```
 chmod +x ./updatescript
```

or by right clicking on the file and making it executable in its properties:

[image]

and run it with this in terminal:

```
 ./updatescript
```

**Note(s):**

There is an option (`-y`) available that can be used with the `upgrade` command so it does not prompt before upgrading the packages. It is a good idea to check what `apt-get` is doing before it upgrades the packages, as it may/will do something stupid or something you don't want it do. More info on options like this can be found by running `man apt-get`.

This also means it is more ideal to use the terminal to run the script, as you can check what it is updating, and then run it. If you want a GUI way to run the updates, use the software-center as that it is what it is for.

Answer (score 10):

Just to add a few points to the excellent answer by @Wilf,

you can run commands in paralell if you want for any reason, for example, an `autostart` script for OpenBox might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

nitrogen --restore &
tint2 &
tilda
```

This will set a background image using `nitrogen`, start the panel `tint2` and start the Quake3-style dropdown console `tilda`, all at the same time. This is useful if you don't need a program to finish before you launch the next one. *Not the case for `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` though!*

Notice the `&` sign at the end of each line. This will cause the shell to fork that process into the background and continue execution. Note how it's different from `&&`, which is basically an `and` sign, `command_1 && command_2` will execute`command_1` and if it exits with success, only then run `command_2`, while `command_1 & command_2` will start the second right after the first.

---

Also, you could just stack commands to have them executed serially, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

This will run `apt-get upgrade` after `apt-get update` is *finished*, but regardless of the result. So even if, for example, the update quits with a network error, the upgrade will still be run.

You can also do this in one line, using the `;` sign: `apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade`. Again, this solution is *not optimal* for these particular commands, but it might come in handy in other situations.

---

One quick final point, you can also break lines containing `&&` as such:

```
command_1 &&
command_2
```

This will be the same as `command_1 && command_2`.